# How to get raiseerror exception from MS SQL Server in hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have Stored procedures, from which client is throwing raiseErrors which we have to get using hibernate. Is there any way to get those warnings from sql using hibernate?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible actions can be use web service that gives you json or soap and you can integrate using spring hibernate.RESTful web service is a good and easy option doing this.

Comment: Hello, thanks, but those raiseErrors are coming from the database I have to catch using hibernate and spring. I am newbie in this framework can you please share some example to get those SQLWarnings.I tried using JDBC where i am able to get those errors as SQLWarnings but i am unable to implement the same using hibernate.